# Html.RenderPartial and Ajax.BeginForm -> Submit is called twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-ajax, partial-views, double-submit-problem

I have the following index view:

```
@model BoringStore.ViewModels.ProductIndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Produkte</h2>

<div id='addProduct'>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("Create", new BoringStore.Models.Product()); }
</div>

<div id='productList'>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("ProductListControl", Model.Products); }
</div>
```

The "productList" is just a list of all products.

The addProduct renders my Create View:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Produkt hinzufügen" style="display:none">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index_AddItem", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "productList" }))
{ 
    @Html.Raw(DateTime.Now.ToString());

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Produkt hinzufügen" />
    </div>
}
```

When submitting the form, the Index_AddItem-method in my controller is called. Unfortunately the form always calls the method twice. :(

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Don't include scripts inside your partial views! They should go the your "main" views or your `_layout.cshtml`.

Your problem is that you have included the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` twice in your page. Once in your `Create` partial and once somewhere else. Because if you include that script multiple times it will subscribe on the submit event multiple times so you will get multiple submit with a single click.

So make sure that you have include that script only once in a page. So move the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` reference into your index view.

Comment: What if you have an Ajax link inside a partial view? The first inclusion of jquery.unobstrusive-ajax doesn't register the link.

Comment: I had the jquery-{version}.js twice in my BundleConfig - once under my jquery bundle and once under ajax bundle. This caused the same issue for me. So thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: I am having a similar issue and I think I may be including something twice I am including jquery-1.10.2, jquery.mask.min.js, jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js, jquery.validate and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax would a combination of these be causing my form to submit twice?

Comment: thanks, its resolved my problem by removing "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" in partial view, it may cause problem when ajax library call multiple time.

Comment: My problem was _Layout.cshtml was being included in my partial view and "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" was included twice.  Setting @Layout = "" resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

insure that you dont have `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` file duplicated in the layout
as mentioned above, and you can check this using browser Inspectors

Another problem which may cause this error that i have encountered is resting a form using jquery in the ajax request as following

```
$("form").trigger("reset"); //just remove this line
```